# Python set attributes during object creation in __new__

Tags: python, object, metaprogramming, dynamic-class-creation

When using __new__ to customize the creation of a metaclass, we can pass attributes to the type().__new__ method which will be set on the object before it is returned, e.g.

```
class Foo(type):    
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['customAttr'] = 'someVal' 
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

So that:

```
>> Foo.__dict__
{'customeAttr': 'someVal', ...}
```

However I don't know how to do the same for a normal (non-meta) class, which causes a problem when using __setattr__:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __new__(cls, someVal):
        obj = object().__new__(cls) # cant pass custom attrs
        obj.customAttr = someVal # obj is already a Bar and invokes __setattr__
        return obj

    def __setattr__(*args): raise Exception('read-only class')
```

So that unfortunately:

```
>>> Bar(42)
...
Exception: read-only class
```

In the __new__ of Bar I get back a fully fledged class instance from object() and any attribute access goes through normal lookup rules, in this case invoking __setattr__. Metaclass Foo avoids this as type() will set attributes before returning the instance during low-level creation whereas object() will not.

Is there a way of passing attributes to object() or is another another type I can use as the instance returned from __new__ that does allow attributes to be set before it becomes a full class instance? I am not interesting in solutions like setting __class__ after instance creation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to explictly bypass your own class's `__setattr__` by calling the `super` or root `object` `__setattr__`. So you'd change:

```
obj.customAttr = someVal
```

to:

```
object.__setattr__(obj, 'customAttr', someVal)
```

A less general approach (doesn't apply to `__slots__` based classes) is to directly assign to `__dict__` using `dict` operations:

```
obj.__dict__['customAttr'] = someVal  # Equivalently: vars(obj)['customAttr'] = someVal
```

The first approach is what [the newly `__slots__`-ed `uuid.UUID`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/uuid.py#L206) now uses; [before it became `__slots__`-ed, it used the second approach](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/uuid.py#L204). In both cases this was needed because they used the same `__setattr__` trick to make the type as immutable as possible (without going to the trouble of subclassing `tuple`, [a la `typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)).